# (413) the package size is too large - MyGet

Tags: myget

When trying to publish to MyGet I get the following error:

```
Failed to publish module 'X': 'Failed to process request. 'The package 
size is too large. The feed owner may have to upgrade the MyGet subscription to resolve this issue.'. 
The remote server returned an error: (413) The package size is too large. The feed owner may have to upgrade the MyGet 
subscription to resolve this issue...
```

The weird thing is that the package is 100MB and the limit is 500MB, for the subscription and maximum package size. We tried deleting some old packages to free space but the error is still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this FAQ in the MyGet Docs and the referenced KB article:
https://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/faq#I_get_a_413_RequestEntityTooLarge_when_pushing_packages_to_my_MyGet_feed

Also check your quota in your MyGet userprofile, which will show the total storage space you currently use. You have two options basically: upgrade your plan, or do some house keeping.